# Unable to find the word that I added to the Huggingface Bert tokenizer vocabulary

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, nltokenizer

I tried to add new words to the `Bert tokenizer vocab`. I see that the length of the vocab is increasing, however I can't find the newly added word in the vocab.

```
tokenizer.add_tokens(['covid', 'wuhan'])

v = tokenizer.get_vocab()

print(len(v))
'covid' in tokenizer.vocab
```

Output:

```
30524

False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling two different things with `tokenizer.vocab` and `tokenizer.get_vocab()`. The first one contains the base vocabulary without the added tokens, while the other one contains the base vocabulary with the added tokens.

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer

t = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

print(len(t.vocab))
print(len(t.get_vocab()))
print(t.get_added_vocab())
t.add_tokens(['covid'])
print(len(t.vocab))
print(len(t.get_vocab()))
print(t.get_added_vocab())
```

Output:

```
30522
30522
{}
30522
30523
{'covid': 30522}
```

Comment: thank you for responding. But I see that the size off the tokeniser has increased but when I do tokenizer.ids_to_tokens[30522] after I add a token I get KeyError: 30522 . What could I be doing wrong here. How do I see the added token?

Comment: @JagadishVishwanatham You can view all of the added tokens as shown in my answer with `t.get_added_vocab()` or with `t.convert_ids_to_tokens(30522)`. for a single token.